# SEO of AngularJs and Laravel with Prerender.io

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, seo, single-page-application, prerender

I am working on a web app using Laravel 5.2 as API and Angularjs as front-end

I am trying to handle SEO on my app and I did the following :

1. removing the '#' form the URL using `<base href="/">` and `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`
2. then I tried to fix the javascript rendered views via [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/)
3. I used  [Prerender middleware for laravel](https://github.com/JeroenNoten/Laravel-Prerender)
4. I have dynamic titles in all my pages i.e titles are rendered from variables decalred in `resolve` function in my routes.

the issue now is titles is get rendered correctly without `{{ }}` but the views inside `ng-view` has only static html  I mean If I called `http://example.com` through Prerender test or any SEO crawler simulator I Just get the header and the footer and some HTML but any data related to database or API requests not rendered

Could you please help me how to let Prerender get the complete page contents before sending it back to the crawler

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you send us an email at support@prerender.io? We'd be happy to look into this for you.

Comment: @Prerender.io Thanks for your concern, I sent you an email already!